# Can I receive multiple messages from Spring AMQP RabbitTemplate at one request?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I want to receive multiple messages on one request from Spring AMQP RabbitTemplate (https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.html).
But I can't find the method working this way. Can I do that in Spring AMQP?

I don't want to use RabbitListener because it consumes all the time..

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such an API on the `RabbitTemplate`, as well as there is no way to send several message per single publish.

You may consider to use this one instead of `receive()`:

```
/**
 * Execute the callback with a channel and reliably close the channel afterwards.
 * @param action the call back.
 * @param <T> the return type.
 * @return the result from the
 * {@link ChannelCallback#doInRabbit(com.rabbitmq.client.Channel)}.
 * @throws AmqpException if one occurs.
 */
@Nullable
<T> T execute(ChannelCallback<T> action) throws AmqpException;
```

So, you can call the `Channel.basicGet()` in a loop on the same opened channel.

However there is also this more higher API:

```
/**
 * Invoke the callback and run all operations on the template argument in a dedicated
 * thread-bound channel and reliably close the channel afterwards.
 * @param action the call back.
 * @param <T> the return type.
 * @return the result from the
 * {@link OperationsCallback#doInRabbit(RabbitOperations operations)}.
 * @throws AmqpException if one occurs.
 * @since 2.0
 */
@Nullable
default <T> T invoke(OperationsCallback<T> action) throws AmqpException {
```

So, you can call `RabbitOperations.receive()` in a loop.

Comment: Right, and with prefetch, the overhead is minimal since the messages are already at the client.